# Android Studio - Inconvertible types cannot cast View to my activity

Tags: java, android

I am new to programming in Android Studio and I got stuck on this error, I cannot find an answer anywhere, so maybe someone can help me.
The error I got is:

> error: incompatible types: View cannot be converted to Chronometer

**Chronometer.java**

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;


public class Chronometer extends AppCompatActivity {

    Chronometer chronometer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chronometer);

        chronometer = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometerID);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please share your XML file too. The layout file? You are trying to convert a view that is not a Chronometer to view.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve over here, you have created a reference to the activity itself and you are trying to cast View returned by findViewById to the activity reference. It would be easier to help if you can elaborate your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chronometer widget class name clashes with your activity name. You can rename your activity or use full name for you widget:

```
android.widget.Chronometer chronometer;

chronometer = (android.widget.Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometerID);
```

Comment: Thank you! This was the problem

Answer (score 1):

Your class extends AppCompatActivity. AppCompatActivity *does not* extend View. `findViewById` returns a View. Therefore this does not work. You cannot convert between types that are in different hierarchies.

Why are you trying to create an instance of your Activity within itself anyway? Generally you would just want to override the lifecycle methods.